# Performance issue with loading a list of cached elements

Tags: database, caching, optimization, ehcache

This is a general cache question, regardless of the code used behind, but for the record I am using Ehcache for Java.

In a classic situation where a system have to load a dynamic list of elements from a database (so query is based on some criteria), are there any known tricks to improve loading performance by leveraging the cache system.

My guess would to be to load a list of IDs instead of a list of elements and then fetch each one of them individually so we can leverage on the caching of the entities.

Thanks for your help.

PS: I hope the question is clear enough. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

The generic answer is: "It all depends".

So, yes, if you expect entities to be cached by IDs, loading a list of IDs and then fetching the cache can be faster. However, you need to be sure of it. Because otherwise, fetching one entity after the other is tremendously slow.

But then, just querying from a DB can be fast too. If it doesn't happen too much. Optimizing DB to Java mapping can improve performance as well.

Some other tricks includes retrieving only the data you need. Not the entire entity. I usually start with that.

So as I said, it depends.